# When to use a list comprehension vs a for loop

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is there a general rule for when a list comprehension is preferred over a `for` loop? For example:

A single for loop is great when converted to a comprehension:

```
l = []
for word in sentence:
    l.append(word)

# [word for word in sentence]
```

A double one might be too:

```
l = []
for word in sentence:
    for letter in word:
        l.append(letter)

# [letter for word in sentence for letter in word]
```

However, I think the readability gets pretty poor after that. For example, with `if`s:

```
l = []
for word in sentence:
    if word.startswith('u'):
        for letter in word:
            if letter in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'o'):
                l.append(letter)

# [letter for word in sentence if word.startswith('u') for letter in word if letter in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'o')]
```

Is there a suggestion for the complexity of a `for` loop pattern where it would be worse trying to put it into a list comprehension?

Comment: I would write it both ways, and test them against each other to verify correctness. Then I would put it aside for a few days. Whichever one is more readable, without being fresh in my mind, would stay.

Comment: both are great ways, but it all comes down to preference and who you are presenting the code to. the for loop approach does shows a more 'methodical' approach as in, everything is clear as is, the comprehension way be it for list or dicts is great for getting the job done quickly.

Comment: On the topic of readability, many people dislike using lower case `l` for list because it looks too much like `1` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer depends on your opinion. However, since I do remember a specific piece of advice of this from an author of a book that is well regarded in the Python community, I can share the following excerpt from the book 'Fluent Python' by Luciano Ramalho:

> A for loop may be used to do lots of different things: scanning a sequence to count or pick items, computing aggregates (sums, averages), or any number of other processing tasks. [...] In contrast, a listcomp is meant to do one thing only: to build a new list.
>
> Of course, it is possible to abuse list comprehensions to write truly incomprehensible code. I’ve seen Python code with listcomps used just to repeat a block of code for its
>   side effects.
>
> If you are not doing something with the produced list, you should not use that syntax.
>
> Also, try to keep it short. If the list comprehension spans more than two lines, it is probably best to break it apart or rewrite as a plain old for loop.  Use your best judgment: for Python as for English, there are no hard-and-fast rules for clear writing.

Comment: I'd agree with this, only thing to add that I haven't seen mentioned yet is: for those cases where nested list comprehension is what you need, you can define each step as a function to improve readability

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/python-basics-list-comprehensions-631278f22c40), performance can be gained.

```
import timeit

def squares(size):
    result = []
    for number in range(size):
        result.append(number*number)
    return result

def squares_comprehension(size):
    return [number*number for number in range(size)]

print(timeit.timeit("squares(50)", "from __main__ import squares", number = 1_000_000))
print(timeit.timeit("squares_comprehension(50)", "from __main__ import squares_comprehension", number = 1_000_000))

5.4292075
4.1652729000000015
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep, list comprehensions have some optimizations which makes them faster than `for` loops, and also `map+filter`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add that you could always work with generators and iterators. There is no major memory overhead, but the performance may suffer unless the innermost operation is relatively costly.

```
from itertools import chain
sentence = "flat is better than nested"

words = sentence.split()
f_words = (w for w in words if w.startswith('f'))
f_chars = chain(*f_words)
good_chars = [c for c in f_chars if c in 'abco']
```