# How to return file names that don't have certain sentences?

Tags: python, for-loop, path

So I made some code that returns the names for each file in a directory.
I want to move on to *filtering* the files that my loop comes across whether that be during the loop itself or during the Path() function. **Help?**

```
from pathlib import Path

# grab all the pdf's, essentially
pdf_files = Path("C:\\Users\\ME\\Documents\\PretendFolder").glob("*.pdf")

for pdf in pdf_files:
        print(pdf)
```

My Output:

`C:\Users\ME\Documents\PretendFolder\Adjusted NO STORY.pdf C:\Users\ME\Documents\PretendFolder\Adjusted.pdf`

My 1st Attempt:

```
canvas = []
for pdf in pdf_files:
    canvas.append(pdf =! 'NO STORY')
    
        print(pdf)
```

My 2nd Attempt:
This second attempt doesn't print anything at all for some reason.

```
pdf_files = Path("C:\\Users\\ME\\Documents\\PretendFolder").glob("*.pdf")

for pdf in pdf_files:
    if not pdf.__contains__('NO STORY'):
         print(pdf)
```

Comment: `canvas = [f for f in pdf_files if 'NO STORY' not in f]` Maybe this would work

Comment: @Chris Would your line of code replace my loop? I'm new to Python!

Comment: yes, it's called a list comprehension and it worth learning

Comment: @Chris It returned a blank list :/

Comment: You can also add one additional line to your `for` loop. Something like `if 'NO STORY' not in pdf.stem:` should do it as well.

Comment: A List Comprehension is functionally equivalent to a for loop used to construct a List but is more concise. You might find this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60627702/when-to-use-a-list-comprehension-vs-a-for-loop) interesting and also other similar references.

Answer (score 1):

You can instead utilize the regular expressions better to filter out the *NO STORY* part.

```
from pathlib import Path

# grab all the PDFs, essentially
pdf_files = Path("C:\\Users\\ME\\Documents\\PretendFolder").glob("^(?!.*NO STORY).*.pdf")

for pdf in pdf_files:
    print(pdf)
```

This will filter out all the PDF files having `NO STORY` in their path.

Comment: I've used regular expressions in R. Do you know if it's possible to filter for more than just the 'NO STORY' case? I have one other case I'd like to filter on called 'CLIENT'.

Comment: Yes, you can pipe the regular expression groups to filter both `NO STORY` and `CLIENT`.